# Why aren't .htaccess rules working on Linux (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have copied a site from my windows machine running WAMP to a Linux machine with a standard LAMP stack.

Everything is working fine apart from the rules in .htaccess. i have confirmed that .htaccess is working by testing a simple rule, so I know its nothing to do with the apache configuration. These rules work absolutely fine on my windows machine.

Here is a copy of the rules from my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?admin=1&class=$1&id=$2&method=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?admin=1&class=$1&method=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?class=$1&id=$2&method=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?admin=1&class=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?class=$1&method=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9-]+.*) index.php?class=downloads&method=download&target=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^stream/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+.*) index.php?class=downloads&method=download&target=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?class=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is there any reason why these wouldn't be working on Linux.

EDIT:

The URL i am requesting is `http://domain.com/access` so i created this rule `RewriteRule access index.php?class=access` which does work.

Comment: The simple rule you tested was presumably a mod_rewrite directive? You must have some more directives than you've posted - please post the entire `.htaccess` file. What URL are you requesting?

Comment: @w3dk Thanks for you're response, i've updated my question. That is the entire `.htaccess` file as well.

Comment: What you have posted would not work by itself in `.htaccess`. You would at least require a `RewriteEngine On` directive. But none of those rules would match a request for `http://domain.com/access` anyway?! However, a request for `http://domain.com/access/` (with a trailing slash) would match the last rule.

Comment: @w3dk I have the `RewriteEngine On` at the top. Thanks for clarifying the slash issue. How would i modify the last rule to not require a trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The URL I am requesting is `http://example.com/access` ...

None of the rules you have posted would match such a request. The last rule requires a trailing slash, so `http://example.com/access/` (with a trailing slash) should work OK.

To make the trailing slash *optional*, you can change the last rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?class=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note the `RewriteRule` *pattern* simply changed from `^(.*)/$` to `^(.*)/?$` - the `?` makes the preceding character/group optional. If the trailing slash is not required at all then remove it.

Answer (score 2):

By default apache has `AllowOverride` disabled, you need to edit apache configuration in file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to enable

Find

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
```

and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Or add to virtualhost config file

```
<Directory /path/to/virtualhost/site>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Also you need to enable rewrite mod if you haven't enabled

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: The OP has already stated that `.htaccess` and mod_rewrite are working OK.